# how to correctly unit test string with parameters

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have a method returning strings with parameters ("toto %s", "tata %s", etc) and I want to test the returned string without caring about the %s replacement.

Example :

```
String testedString = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getString(R.string.my_string_with_parameter);
assertEquals(testedString, returnedString);
```

fail because :

> Expected :STARTS IN %s
>
> Actual   :STARTS IN 321 DAYS

but I can't know inside my test that %s is replaced by "321 days".

Is there a way to properly testing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
assertThat(testedString, startsWith("STARTS IN"));
```

to test for the fixed part of the result.

In order to fully test this, you need to make sure that the code under test returns a fixed value for the time value that is inserted.
I am not familiar with the code that is executed, but there is probably some way in that you can control and or mock this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
    public void stringIsCorrect(String desiredSubstring, String generatedString){
        assertTrue(generatedString.indexOf(desiredString) != -1);
    }
```

If you need it to be more flexible, you can replace the first argument with a List and loop through them, as well as use the Apache StringUtils to check if the substrings appear the correct number of times.